# Amazon MWS CreateShipment fails with Fedex every time with no real error

Tags: amazon-mws

I am using the Amazon C# SDK to call CreateShipment and buy shipping labels from Amazon.

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/merch_fulfill/MerchFulfill_CreateShipment.html

We use the same code 100's of times a day to buy USPS and UPS lables but it fails 100% of the time trying to buy Fedex labels.

This is the error response we get which is not descriptive.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/MerchantFulfillment/2015-06-01">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>470076a3-781e-4fa9-8b8e-796c3fd286ef</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Here is our request xml straight from the SDK. I only substituted place holders instead of our actual information.

```
<CreateShipmentRequest
    xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/MerchantFulfillment/2015-06-01">
    <SellerId>{selelr id}</SellerId>
    <ShipmentRequestDetails>
        <AmazonOrderId>{amazon order id}</AmazonOrderId>
        <ItemList>
            <Item>
                <OrderItemId>{amazon item id}</OrderItemId>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </Item>
        </ItemList>
        <ShipFromAddress>
            <Name>{ship from name}</Name>
            <AddressLine1>{ship from address}</AddressLine1>
            <Email>{email}</Email>
            <City>{city}</City>
            <StateOrProvinceCode>{state}</StateOrProvinceCode>
            <PostalCode>{zip code}</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <Phone>{phone number}</Phone>
        </ShipFromAddress>
        <PackageDimensions>
            <Length>32.00</Length>
            <Width>23.50</Width>
            <Height>2.50</Height>
            <Unit>inches</Unit>
        </PackageDimensions>
        <Weight>
            <Value>120.00</Value>
            <Unit>ounces</Unit>
        </Weight>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
            <DeliveryExperience>DeliveryConfirmationWithoutSignature</DeliveryExperience>
            <CarrierWillPickUp>False</CarrierWillPickUp>
            <LabelFormat>PDF</LabelFormat>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
    </ShipmentRequestDetails>
    <ShippingServiceId>FEDEX_PTP_HOME_DELIVERY</ShippingServiceId>
</CreateShipmentRequest>
```

What is it about my request that won't work with Fedex? For the record I have tried every label type available. The same issue with each one.

I also submitted about 10 cases with Amazon support. They never respond.

[UPDATE]
The issue ended up being the label format. Apparently I had a bug in my code so it was always asking for a PDF label. Amazon does not support PDF labels with Fedex. They only support PNG and ZPL.